# SQLite and development

Tags: sqlite, browser, ionic3, native

I work on a new app, and I need advice.

I need to use SQLite on the device, but I can't use ionic serve with SQLite.

How can I create a "global" provider who can switch between the two (browser and sqlite)?

Comment: This is for ionic 2 buy i do not think it has changed: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-sqlite-and-crhome-webrowser-for-test-app/69035

Comment: Perfect, thank you!